# how to fetch the value of one node based on the value from another node

Tags: xslt

I want to fetch the "index" value based on what is present in the string

```
<sch name="main">
    <norm string="back-slash"/>
    <norm string="open-braces" />
    <norm string="close-braces" />
</sch>
<strings  name="consts">
  <string name="back-slash" val="\\" index="0"/>
  <string name="close-braces" val="]" index="2"/>
  <string name="remove-null" val="null" index="3" /> 
</strings>
```

i tried this but it doesnt' work. Can yuou please help?

```
<xsl:template match="norm" >
 <xsl:variable name="$nme" select="@string"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="/strings/@name=$nme/@index"/>,
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/strings/@name=$nme/@index
```

is not valid XPath. You need an attribute selector if you wish to target a node by one of its attributes.

```
/strings/*[@name=$nme]/@index
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the name of your variable `$nme` is not a valid Qname.

Instead of

```
<xsl:variable name="$nme" select="@string"/>
```

you should use

```
<xsl:variable name="nme" select="@string"/>
```

try this template:

```
<xsl:template match="norm" >
    <xsl:variable name="nme" select="@string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::strings/string[@name=$nme]/@index"/>,
</xsl:template>
```